# TFS Shelveset - Can't find my sets

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, shelveset

I just shelved some changes in TFS. It worked, because I saw the results in the output window. I immediately tried to find the new shelveset. From the Pending Changes window, I selected Find Shelvesets under Actions, and saw my correct username, but no shelvesets were found.

Help.

Sorry, but this is all I have to go on...

Comment: WAIT! I got an error when shelving. A file I no longer used couldn't be found. Does this mean that the shelveset wasn't created???

Answer (score 0):

try doing this from the command line, just in case Visual Studio has got into a mess. Browse to a folder mapped in a local workspace first. The command should open a dialog that lists the possible shelvesets.

`tf unshelve`

Answer (score 0):

My comment to my own question has the answer. It didn't create the shelveset because of errors. Duh!